# При создании пула как работает параметр connectionLimit?

Tags: mysql, node.js

connectionLimit при создании пула соединений с mysql выставляет ограничения для конкретного пользователя? Т.е если я выставлю это значение на 2 то только условно я буду делать только 2 запроса одновременно или в целом 2 запроса от всех пользователей?

Answer (score 0):

Если пул в процессе, то ограничение на процесс. Запрос занимает один из коннектов. Второй запрос следующий коннект. Когда коннекты закончились вызов блокируется пока не освободится один из них.

Если пул создаешь внутри обработчика - это новый пул на каждый запрос. Так делать не рекомендуется из-за производительности.

Количество соединений подбирается с расчетом того сколько запросов нужно отработать одновременно, но при этом не забив забив ввод-вывод на сервере БД.